# Is multiple times overwriting a file, safe with fstream

Tags: c++, fstream, ofstream

Will fstream overwriting a file multiple times cause any problems?

Comment: This is too broad. What problem are you worried about specifically?

Comment: I am worried about the file getting corrupted.

Comment: @StephenJacob If your computer corrupts files when they are overwritten you need to get a new computer, or at least a new storage device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it will not. Try this, you won't get any problems.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main(){

    ofstream out;

    for(int cnt = 0; cnt < 100; ++cnt){
        out.open("file.txt");
        out << "This will be written 100 times, and erased 99 times.";
        // Uncomment the lines below if you want to see each change
        //out << " Run#: " << cnt;
        //cin.get();
        out.close();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

*Disclaimer: I did not try to run this code. Apologies if there are any syntax errors.*

Comment: please explain further what is happening. No it is not can mean it is not safe to overwrite multiple times file with fstream (title) and it can mean no it is not unsafe to overwrite file with fstream.